# Is there a single word for "deep-sea exploration/diving"?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Examples:

> The bathysphere was a pioneer in *[deep-sea exploration]*.
>
> I prepared to embark on a *[deep-sea dive]*.

A technical noun/gerund term is preferred. If one does not exist, clearly marked suggestions for newly coined terms (probably beginning with "bathy-") are fine.

Comment: *Oceanography?*

Comment: Too broad. _Oceanography_ encompasses a huge swath of topics of which deep-sea exploration is only a small part. It also cannot be manipulated into a single term for the second example above.

Comment: The full OED has **bathymetry** - *The art or science of measuring **depths** (in the sea)*. Also **bathyal**, but that's defined as *pertaining to the zone **between** the continental shelf and the abyssal zone*, which presumably isn't what you want either.

Comment: _Bathymetry_ is specifically underwater topography, and generally doesn't even require diving at all.

Comment: Well, you could go for a "neologism" - but you wouldn't be the first: [*This field might be called “**bathology**,” for it goes beyond the task of making a chart by asking, “What do these cotours tell us about the physical processes operating on the sea-bottom?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22might+be+called+bathology%22) Failing that I think you'll be out of luck here.

Comment: You could always go for *Cousteauing*, or maybe *frogmaning*.

Comment: ["Demersal Dive"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458926/statically-sized-or-static-sized-buffers/458928?noredirect=1#comment1105654_458928) has been suggested by a new user who doesn't *quite* yet have the rep to post a comment. If anyone follows that link, give him a leg up the rep ladder with an upvote, then when he gets to 50 he can speak for himself!

Comment: @ubi-hatt _Demersal_ looks promising! Synonymous with _benthic_, both have useful roots to add to the search.

Comment: Following that line, I hopefully looked up _demersion_, but that already has an unpleasantly conflicting definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## demersal-dive

I'll like to *suggest* "**demersal-dive**". The word demersal is bit too technical in terms of Oceanography (demersal zone) and Marine biology (demersal).

Definition of [**demersal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demersal) in Merriam-Webster is given as follows:

> **living near, deposited on**, or sinking to the bottom of the sea.

Definition of [**demersal**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demersal) in Oxford is given as follows:

> (chiefly of fish) living close to the floor of the sea or a lake. 
>   Origin: Late 19th century: from **Latin demersus** (past participle of **demergere** ‘submerge, sink’, from de- ‘down’ + mergere ‘plunge’) + -al.

The  **Demersal zone** in the sea/ocean.

> The demersal zone is the part of the sea or ocean (or deep lake) consisting of the part of the water column **near to (and significantly affected by) the seabed and the benthos**. The demersal zone is just above the benthic zone and forms a layer of the larger profundal zone. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demersal_zone)

There is a rare usage of the phrase "**Demersal Divers**" as in the book: [Writes of Passage by Phil Wallace Payne](https://books.google.com/books?id=xDdlczwYt_cC&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=Demersal+Dive&source=bl&ots=ZzVt2SCJTM&sig=LdLHZXRR6slt2naP50_OMnQMXDE&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Demersal%20Dive&f=false).

Oxford dictionary states that ["demersal"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demersal) is often contrasted with [pelagic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pelagic). **Pelagic** (chiefly of fish or of a bird) **inhabiting the upper layers of the open sea**.

Answer (score 2):

A technical term used for the deep sea diving and exploration within the jargon of the deep sea branch of oceanography is ***benthic exploration***. I've found this term used in various sources about oceanography and deep sea topics. *Benthic* is the adjective form of the noun *benthos*, which is the term used for the flora and fauna at or near the bottom of the sea. It comes from Greek *βένθος* meaning "depth of the sea"<sup>[OED]</sup>. Additionally, *benthic zone* is the term used for the lowest ecological zone in a water body.

Here are some usages of the term *benthic exploration*:

> **Benthic exploration science** is evolving, looking to answer more sophisticated questions regarding drivers of biodiversity, patterns of reproduction and recruitment, genetic and ecosystem connectivity, oceanographic influences on benthic diversity and abundance, and trophic connectivity (McClain and Rex, 2015; McClain and Schlacher, 2015; Baco et al., 2016).
>
> <sub>*[Pacific Deep-Sea Discoveries: Geological and Biological Exploration, Patterns, and Processes](https://books.google.es/books?id=9b0pEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA112&dq=%22benthic%20exploration%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjitNqu_9D4AhU4QfEDHQAUCH8Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22benthic%20exploration%22&f=false)* - edited by Randi D. Rotjan, Diva Amon, William W. Chadwick, Stephen Hammond</sub>

> In this respect, Antarctica poses severe challenges for the **benthic ecologist**. Most of the Southern Ocean overlies the abyssal plain, the continental shelves are unusually deep, and access is impeded by floating ice shelves or vast areas of seasonal pack-ice. Despite these difficulties there is a long and proud history of **benthic exploration** in the Antarctic, and we now know a good deal about the fauna, at least for the major taxa of the continental shelves.
>
> <sub>*[Oceanography and Marine Biology, An Annual Review, Volume 41](https://books.google.es/books?id=64crGFXWn5gC&pg=PA80&dq=benthic%20exploration&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmybyB_9D4AhW_RvEDHeekAXgQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=benthic%20exploration&f=false)* - edited By R. N. Gibson, R. J. A. Atkinson</sub>

As a single word option, I propose ***benthography*** akin to *oceanography*. The term appears in a few technical sources online. Furthermore, *benthograph*, an unmanned deep sea vehicle, is used already as a more established term. *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/benthograph)* definition of *benthograph*:

> an instrument consisting of a hollow steel sphere that contains cameras and lighting equipment and is designed for underwater photographic exploration at great depths

Another option is ***benthology*** which is used in various sources; however, it would be used as an all-encompassing term for the study of the deep sea or benthic zone.