# "Statically sized" or "Static-sized" buffers?

Tags: meaning, grammar

I mean to say that the size of the buffers is fixed and won't change. I wonder wich way is more appropriate.

For example:

"Our approach employs statically sized buffers to avoid the overhead associated with resizing."

Comment: Could you provide us with a phrase in which the word in question could be used?

Comment: They're both valid, as is a [*static **size** buffer.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22static+size+buffer%22) But [***fixed-size buffer***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fixed-size+buffer%22) is far more common, and avoids the confusion in your usage caused by the fact that "static" variables aren't the same thing as variables dynamically allocated on the stack, regardless of their ***size***.

Comment: Your example needs the indefinite article ***a** statically sized buffer* (or pluralise to ***buffers*** if you use more than one).

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's a good point. I think I'll go with that.  I meant to say "buffers" in the example.

Comment: I hope your example really is just a hypothetical one though. Fixed-size buffers are one of the leading causes of insecure software, and with multiple layers of progressively faster (but *smaller*) memory stores, it might turn out that an app that allocates huge fixed (but potentially still vulnerable) buffers actually runs *slower* because unnecessarily large chunks have to thread their way up the memory caches to the processor (still waiting for memory i/o, when it could long ago have eaten for breakfast the trivial task of resizing! :)

Comment: It is not hypothetical. It is actually a good approach in computer graphics to render multiple instances of the same model, in some cases.

Comment: [However,  as recent GPUs share virtual and even physical memory with CPUs, **buffer overflows in GPU can also lead to security and correctness problems**. Existing tools to detect GPU buffer overflow, such as Oclgrind, may incur latency overheads of up to 300 times.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314099546_Dynamic_buffer_overflow_detection_for_GPGPUs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use "**static buffer(s)**" or "**fixed-size buffer(s)**". Technically, Fixed Size buffer is more appropriate and widely used.

> "Our approach employs a static sized buffers to avoid the overhead associated with resizing."

or

> "Our approach employs a fixed-sized buffers to avoid the overhead associated with resizing."

Comment: Haha! You included *both* ways to fix the grammar, as I suggested in a comment before. But you're quite right on the substance, of course. I leave it to you as a new user to edit your own post (whichever way round you fancy! :)

Comment: Would not it be better to use a hyphen, as in "fixed-size", to emphasize that the size is fixed and not the buffer?

Comment: @BrunoNascimento it is debatable, but it can be used. I guess, I will edit my answer with Hyphen, it looks more readable.

Comment: @BrunoNascimento: Most people [don't include the hyphen](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fixed-size%2Cfixed+size&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfixed%20-%20size%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfixed%20size%3B%2Cc0), and I really don't think it's relevant to consider possible ambiguity (or "shade of meaning"). Albeit slow, the tendency is always towards simplification of orthography, so I'd expect the preference for not hyphenating to strengthen in coming years.

Comment: That's 2 edits already, but you still haven't addressed [***a** statically sized buffer,* or pluralise to ***buffers**!*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458926/statically-sized-or-static-sized-buffers/458928#comment1105619_458926)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Technically, fixed size buffer is use. That is what I have studied while in Uni. But, if someone what's to insist on using Static Size buffer then it is ok!

Comment: @FumbleFingers sorry for that!

Comment: @ubihatt: But do you not agree that ***static[ally]*** carries unwanted and potentially distracting / confusing associations with the special significance of "static" in many programming languages? Both static and dynamic pointer variables  may reference both fixed-size and dynamically-allocated data spaces.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought to avoid getting bit too technical here and restricted my answer to the domain of English. That's is one reason I emphasised on 'fixed sized' buffer. Actually, he/she should have asked it in CS SE with tag terminology, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. I'm inclined to think it's Off Topic "domain-specific usage" that should be on CS SE. But there's no preset "migration path" for that, and it happens to be an area of interest to many here on ELU anyway, so I didn't think it would be right to vote to close. But your answer is fine, and doesn't get bogged down in the opinion-based "hyphenate or not?" issue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers on the other question [Is there a single word for deep sea exploration diving](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458914/is-there-a-single-word-for-deep-sea-exploration-diving) can we use "Demersal Dive"? Though, demersal is mainly associated with life forms found near the bottom of the sea? Don't have enough reputation to comment there :(

Comment: Current rep 44 - you'll be able to comment pretty soon, I'm sure! But you might consider *answering*, which doesn't have a rep threshold.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you are kind and I have answered that [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458914/is-there-a-single-word-for-deep-sea-exploration-diving). Let's see how OP responds.

Answer (score 0):

The more technical term is "statically allocated" (viz dynamically allocated). With static allocation all your memory is prepared in advance at compile time as opposed to an on demand run-time allocation from a pool. With size, it refers to a buffer in use, whereas allocation has a wider inference of its capability before it is filled and the memory management practices in place.

As an example in c++ you have methods size and capacity for a vector. The first is how much is currently utilised. The second is how much has been allocated (that is how much you can fill before needing a resize option)

It's not just correct in a technical sense. Semantically, statically sized is incorrect. Sizing refers to measurement and so statically is the incorrect adverb. Other terms such as "fixed size" are correct, but do not convey what you want to say as well as "statically allocated".